# Equation of Earth's Orbit around Sun (ellipse)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The preihelion is the smallest distance from a planet to the sun, and aphelion is the greatest distance. The sun is one of the two foci. For the Earth, the perihelion is 147.1 million km and the aphelion is 152.1 million km. These two distances help identify the location of the sun on the major axis of Earth's elliptical orbit.

Assume that the major axis of Earth is on the x-axis.

a. Find an equation of the Earth's orbit about the sun.

b. With the given information,  estimate Earth's speed around the sun in milers per hour.

So I'm thinking half the total distance of the aphelion and perihelion would give half the major axis. ($\frac{147.1+152.1}{2}=149.6$) My problem is how would I find the length of the minor axis?
$$\frac{x^2}{149.6^2}+\frac{y^2}{?}=1$$ Thanks for any help!

Comment: The other focus is at distance  147.1 million km  from the aphelion location. Hence the distance between the two foci is ... and you can compute the minor axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are given $a-f$ and $f+f+a-f=a+f$, from which you get $a$ and $f$ and then $b$ from $f=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

All the equations you need are in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) on the ellipse.  You are correct that the semi-major axis is the average of perihelion and aphelion.  The difference between either one of them and the semi-major axis is the distance from the center to the focus, which gives you the eccentricity and you are on your way.

Answer (score 0):

The equation can be very easily determined by simply using 2 formulae of ellipse 
• prehelion= semi major axis × (1 -e)
• square of semi minor axis= square of semi major axis  ( 1-e^2)
Here e is eccentricity 
Thus semi minor axis on solving = 149.58 million Kms.
So the equation is 
(X÷149.6)^2 + (Y÷149.58)^2 = 1